Can application record itself using Media Projection single app option (Android 14)?
I'm trying to record the screen of the application which starts recording using Media Projection, with "A single app" option, introduced in Android 14. In the second part of createScreenCaptureIntent, where I need to select which application screen I want to record my own application doesn't show up.
Step 1
Step 2
I've found this error in the logs, I'm guessing it has to do with it.
ChooserActivity E  Failed to get target intent filter: intent data and type are null
Also I've found this application called "XRecorder" which can record itself.
XRecorder step 2
Here is my manisfest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION" />
<uses-permission android:name="Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ScreenRecorderExample"
    tools:targetApi="34">

    <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".service.MediaProjectionService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true">
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>

